# How to avoid textbox drop down list in JSP?

Tags: jsp, browser, drop-down-menu, textbox

When we are entering the username in a textbox in a browser, the recently used usernames are shown in a drop down list automaticaly. I want to avoid this for the secure web page.

How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666480/jsp-autocomplete-off-not-working-in-chrome-or-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `autocomplete="off"` attribute in the `<input />` tag. If this does not work in certain browsers, you can use a *cross-browser-compatibility* workaround :

```
<input type="text" style="display: none;" autocomplete="off"/>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

This tricks the browser into auto-filling the hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

are you heard a term called autoComplete..

```
<input name="q" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

[REFERENCE](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/autocomplete-off/)

Comment: @utiltty ohh god.. how intelligent you are :) .. thanks for your advice

Comment: Thank you @Sarath.please go through : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666480/jsp-autocomplete-off-not-working-in-chrome-or-firefox